# How to delete rows with decimal points from a column of mixed type Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm wondering how to delete rows with decimal points from a column of mixed type in a Pandas data frame.

Suppose I have a column of mixed type (type 'o').

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2.3, 'Level1']}
test1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

test1['col1'].dtypes
dtype('O')

test1
    col1
0   1
1   2.3
2   Level1
```

I will like to delete the row that contains decimal points.

```
test1
    col1
0   1
2   Level1
```

I tried str.isdecimal() or str.contain('.') didn't work.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2.3, 'Level1']}
test1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

test2 = test1.copy()

for i in range(len(test1)):
  if "." in str(test1.iloc[i,0]):
    test2.drop(i, axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regex?

```
m = test1['col1'].astype(str).str.fullmatch('\d+\.\d+')

test1[~m]
```

Or testing the real object type:

```
m = test1['col1'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float))

test1[~m]
```

Output:

```
     col1
0       1
2  Level1
```